# Game/Quote of the day - how to?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have `List<T>` that contains games.
i want to select 1 game from that list that will be the game of the day.

i have no idea on how i can do that. Please, contribute your ideas.

EDIT:
Random will not work, since every page load the game will change.
There are no specific limits for the game selection ( votes,rating,whatever ).
There should be a connection to the date due at least thats what i have in mind.

if a random game could be select by the current date, thats the perfect solution.

Comment: You should give a criterion for the decision... randomness, popularity, other... ?

Comment: Bit vague... `gameList[0]` would seem to work if there's something in the list

Comment: If today's game of the day was Halo, would it be OK if tomorrow was also Halo? One day next week?

Comment: Well, Preferably not.
i think i have a solution, working on it now. will post an answer if it works.

Comment: Assuming you have fewer than 365 games: `int gameOfTheDay = DateTime.DayOfYear % NumberOfGames;`

Comment: what will happen if i have more then that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var gameOfTheDay = games[(uint)(DateTime.Today.GetHashCode()) % games.Length];
```

Comment: Great !
The only thing i had to add was Math.Abs since the values were negative.

Comment: Corrected. Obviously this still allows the game of the day to be the same two days in a row, so it would be better to choose at random taking account of previous choices, or actually have some personal editorial input and make a human choose!

Comment: Let's hope that `DateTime.Today.GetHashCode()` never returns `int.MinValue`. Otherwise your `Math.Abs` is going to throw an exception.

Comment: You also need to watch out for changing the number of games during the day, otherwise you could end up changing the right hand side of your `%` and having two or more 'game of the day' in a single day...

Comment: @Matt - Currently, our editors are really busy in writing game reviews. It will be considerd when the time comes.
 @Jim - Thanks, i added a Try..Catch block.
 @forsvarir - Thanks for the comment, but if that happens, i would not care much of it. since timezones are mistery for users on websites ( usually ), a change like that will not make a serious problem.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Good spot, fixed the code by casting to unsigned int rather than using Math.Abs.

Comment: i tried adding the new code, but for some reason it dosent like the (uint), if i put a (int) it works due.
any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

```
var random = new Random();
var index = random.Next(0, gameList.Count - 1);
var gameOfTheDay = gameList[index];
```

Comment: i am currently using a random, but a random will change the game on each page load.
i am looking for a solution based on Random + Date....

Comment: Why can't you store the selected game somewhere (like in a database if an web app)?

Comment: @Rephael: You could use DateTime.DayOfYear as seed

Comment: i am not using a db.
and i prefer not using app/session objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Random.Next Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx) to get a random index:

```
var random = new Random();
int index = random.Next(list.Count);
var game = list[index];
```

Given the list has at least one element, obviously.

Comment: a) Your code will fail sometimes since `list.Count` is out of range. b) `Next` is not static.

Comment: True with a), corrected it, thanks. However, isn't `list.Count - 1` the largest number `Next(list.Count)` may return? MSDN: "Returns a nonnegative random number less than the specified maximum."