# Linq OrderBy GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

ok, lets see if i can explain this.

i have a `List<Games> _Games = new List<Games>();` which containts 870 Games.

i have a Title ( each page will have a diffrent title, which is not related to the games, but the page will have the same game count ).

now, what i want to do, is order the games, based by the title i provide.

i actually tried to do something like this:

`_Games = _Games.OrderByDescending(g => Math.Abs(Title.GetHashCode()));`

but the order of the games stays the same.

Anyone has an idea how this kind of sorting can be created?

EDIT: you can see something similar to what i try to acheive here : [Game/Quote of the day - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058802/game-quote-of-the-day-how-to)

but the accpeted answer there returns only 1 game, i want to return all the games.

EDIT: Sample title's :  "Hello World", "Goodbye" === Diffrent Titles...

EDIT: this was conceptual.. added `_Games =` so you wont fixate on small things like that and avoiding my real question.

Comment: do you mean `_Games.OrderByDescending(g => Math.Abs(g.Title.GetHashCode()));` ?

Comment: You are sorting by a value which is independent of each game `g`, therefore the sort (which I presume is stable) leaves your collection untouched. Also `GetHashCode` is a very strange choice of sort criterion.

Comment: @Bala - no, since as i said the game and title are not connected.

Comment: @Jon - i figured that out, but how can i do something similar to that.

Comment: It's still completely unclear what you want to do. It's like saying "I have a number, e.g. 42, and want to sort the list of games based on it". It simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: I want to semi randomize the list, based on a value, is that more clear?
at the end of the day, i want each page to show a randomized list of games, but each page should have a unique random list, so a page named "Hello World" will allways show the same order of the games,
while "Goodbye" will show its own order of the games. but, i dont want every entrance to "Goodbye" to change the order.

Comment: I agree with Jon.  You can't order something by a value that doesn't relate.  Phone books are ordered by Last Name. You could order it by first name, or phone number but not by the Month which doesn't relate.

Comment: Based on your comment, are you asking for random sort, that uses the title as the random key?

Comment: @Jeff Reddy - i dont agree with you, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058802/game-quote-of-the-day-how-to and see the accepted answer. it is selected by DayOfTheWeek, which has no relation to the games. the problem with that code is that it returns only 1 game.

Comment: See my second comment.  Your not looking to sort the games, but make a random selection based upon a key, and you want to get a different list for each key, but the the same random list for each key.  I would re-word your question.

Comment: Well, Me English Bad. :D
But, yes, i think that you are right.

Comment: @Dementic: There is a small difference between your code and mine. You need to bring `g` into role. Try doing `.OrderByDescending(g => Math.Abs(g.Name+Title.GetHashCode()));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ordering attempt has two problems:

1.) You try to order by a fixed value (the hash code of the title) - ordering is internally done by most sort routines by comparing two items and positioning them accordingly. Now if you project each item to a fixed value they all are coming up as equal and no sort order can be established.

2.) You are not re-assigning the results of your ordering to your collection. You probably want something like

```
_Games = _Games.OrderByDescending(g => g.Title).ToList();
```

**Edit:**

Judging by your comments you just want to shuffle the list of games using a random sequence that will always be the same for a given title. If so, you can use a Fisher-Yates Shuffle combined with a Random instance that you pass the hash code of the title:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
{
    T[] elements = source.ToArray();
    // Note i > 0 to avoid final pointless iteration
    for (int i = elements.Length-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        // Swap element "i" with a random earlier element it (or itself)
        int swapIndex = rng.Next(i + 1);
        T tmp = elements[i];
        elements[i] = elements[swapIndex];
        elements[swapIndex] = tmp;
    }
    // Lazily yield (avoiding aliasing issues etc)
    foreach (T element in elements)
    {
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Random rng = new Random(Title.GetHashCode());
_Games = _Games.Shuffle(rng).ToList();
```

Keep in mind though that hash codes are not guaranteed to be stable, they can differ between platforms (.NET 32 vs 64 bit) and on each run time of your executable - it is only guaranteed that the same title will produce the same hash code within one execution of your program. If this is a problem for you, you might have to switch to your own method of determining a unique value for each title, i.e.:

```
Random rng = new Random(GetUniqueValue(Title));
```

Comment: how come its a fixed value if specificly declare that each page has a diffrent title ?

Comment: how is the page title related to a game / your list of games?

Comment: it is not... that is the question, how can i order the Games, by the a provided title...

Comment: @Dementic: If there is no relationship and just a *single* title you cannot sort the collection this way. There has to be a defined projection for each game to the title it should be represented as in the sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is effectivily saying:

```
_Games.OrderByDescending(1);
```

Because the number in Title.GetHashCode() does not change for each game, thus there is no ordering applied on the items. From your description, it is unclear how you want the order of the _Games items to change for each page. Typically, you would do something along the lines of:

```
_query = _Games.OrderByDescending(g => Math.Abs(g.Title.GetHashCode()));
```

But, you don't show how Title is related to the Game itself to know if this makes sense.

Comment: I think TItle and g.Title are completely different animals e.g.:
Page1.Title = "Welcome NY Gamers", Page2.Title = "Welcome WA Gamers", Game1.Title = "CandyLand", Game2.Title = "Shoots and Ladder's".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Linq very well, but here's my guess.  It probably doesn't even compile, but I think the general idea might be what you're after...

```
Random r = new Random(Title.GetHashCode());
Dictionary<object, int> map = new Dictionary<object, int>(_Games.Count);
foreach( object game in _Games )
{
    map.Add(game, r.nextInt());
}
_Games = _Games.OrderByDescending( g => map[g] );
```

This will give you a consistent ordering for each title, and the ordering should be different between titles.  (In some cases two different titles might share an ordering but it'll be rare.)

Edit:
Forgot to give _Games a consistent pre-order before applying the random sort...  (Note: This algorithm has infinite slowdown potential depending on how the sort is implemented, but with only 850 games I doubt you'll see a problem)

Also, the pre-order could be more stable if _Game has a better attribute to sort on like a .Title() of it's own...

Edit2: Looks like Linq does some interesting optimizations when the variable isn't passed in, looks like a mapping is needed...

Comment: What part isn't working?  Won't compile?  Infinite loop?  Inconsistent ordering across restarts of the program?  Something else?

Comment: I edited your code to compile, but i still get the Same ordering on everypage, just as the original code i wrote.

Comment: Edited to use a map instead of:
**_Games = _Games.OrderByDescending( g => r.nextInt() );**
which was apparently optimized out.

Answer (score 0):

`OrderByDescending` is a pure method, i.e. it doesn't change the enumerable it is called on. You need to assign the return value to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an access to my development machine so cant try prctically. Plz try using

```
Games.OrderByDescending(g=>g.GameName.GetHashCode()+PageTitle.GetHashCode())
```

or

```
Games.OrderByDescending(g=>(g.GameName+Title).GetHashCode())
```

*One thing that I can conclude from your requirement is
you need to setup a relationship between your list items(games) with any custom logic that will generate same value for each page(page specific value will be same). without linking your list with custom logic will not give you a list that you are looking for. So you will any how bring g into the play along with your custom logic.*

Comment: that will still wont work. and if i will add the random number.. well, the results will allways be diffrent for the same page. since `GetHashCode` will return a diffrent int value for each title, there is no diffrence between your code and mine.

Comment: basically you cant use random no. so I am giving an idea to use some logic that would be page dependent. you need to first sort the page by any key adding page name as one of its part and then make a selection of top 100 or whatever no of records you want to show. You are actually asking for random selection(key remaining same for page) with same records on each page,

Comment: @Dementic: Here I am not adding the random no that is what I am trying to focus. See there are two parts in the logic 1st `g.GameName.GetHashCode()` which will generate same code for all list items i.e. each Game Name will generate their own hash code 2nd part `PageTitle.GetHashCode()` for page 1 it will generate eg '123123 then next time also it will generate same code when I will be coming to the page 1 but on page 2 it will generate different code. Now since I added this no to each list item's hash code and then sorted on this resulting no will generate different list for me on each page.

Comment: Only difference between what you are doing an I am doing is relating g with your code. in your code `Math.Abs(Title.GetHashCode()));` you didn't used g any where which is the point of my focus . you only need to add g.Item in relation to Title

Comment: having or not having the `g.` in there is not making any diffrence. since after all: `g.GameName.GetHashCode()+PageTitle.GetHashCode()` equal an integer. so even if your interger is 32, and `Title.GetHashCode()` is 14, it still dosent matter.